Tuya OAuth2 sign invalid
I have a problem with OAuth2 authorization with Tuya. The code I posted below comes from their documentation + there are minor corrections according to the support instructions. Unfortunately, despite everything, the response from the server is still "sign invalid". I do everything according to the recommendations but it still doesn't work. The "code" token is refreshed. Can anyone help me?
async function getToken() {
  const method = 'GET';
  const timestamp = Date.now().toString();
  const signUrl = '/v1.0/token?code=481d2bb7a81afaac7c2b7d92876ee5ab&grant_type=2';
  const contentHash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update('').digest('hex');
  const stringToSign = [method, contentHash, '', signUrl].join('\n');
  const signStr = config.accessKey + timestamp + stringToSign;

  const headers = {
    t: timestamp,
    sign_method: 'HMAC-SHA256',
    client_id: config.accessKey,
    sign: await encryptStr(signStr, config.secretKey),
  };

  const { data: login } = await httpClient.get('/v1.0/token?code=481d2bb7a81afaac7c2b7d92876ee5ab&grant_type=2', { headers });
  if (!login || !login.success) {
    throw Error(login);
  }
  token = login.result.access_token;
}

